# How Can I set the time-to-live (TTL) on a message sent by @JmsListener

Tags: spring-jms

I am using the @JmsListener from spring-jms  4.1.6 in my application, and I would like to set a TTL on the responses sent to the JMSReplyTo field.  I am having a difficult time trying to do this easily.  I am newer to spring-jms, so I think that I might be overlooking something.

To set the TTL, I had to

- create a CustomJmsListenerAnnotationBeanProcessor,
- which creates a CustomMethodJmsListenerEndpoint for each annotated method,
- which overrides createMessageListenerInstance
- which creates a CustomMessagingMessageListenerAdapter
- which overrides postProcessProducer as below:

  ```
  protected void postProcessProducer(MessageProducer, Message response) throws JMSException {
     super.postProcessProducer(producer, response);
     producer.setTimeToLive(10000);
  }
  ```

Ok.   So this all seems like insanity, especially because postProcessProducer is buttoned up so nicely, and because MessagingMessageListenerAdapter has a factory method.  It seems like this method was meant to be intercepted an overridden.   This brings me to my questions:

- It seems like setting the TTL on responses would be a commonly done thing, so the myriad of overrides to do it seems wrong.  Am I overlooking a simpler way to set the TTL on responses?
- Am I overlooking a simpler way to inject MessagingMessageListenerAdapter children given that it appears it is meant to be overridden?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have the same problem, check this out: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13774

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach is correct. They have also implemented support for it:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13774

So now you can extend `CustomJmsListenerAnnotationBeanProcessor` without coping whole class.